# How to capture Apache flume Meta data information of the data that is being transferred

Tags: hadoop, flume

I have tried to capture the Apache Flume meta data information, but I'm not seen where its logs this information.

Please do let me know if I need to do any pre-configuration to capture the Flume meta data information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by metadata? What information do you need to capture?

Comment: Thanks for responding: what I mean here is,If apache flume transfers a file or log from source to destination, is it possible to capture where its transfering file and the amount of data is being transfered, where does flume store all this information. If I'm wrong understanding of metadata,please do let me know. Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Flume components logs some of such meta-information in standard Flume log (/var/log/flume-ng).

For example, [HDFS sink](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#hdfs-sink) logs the path of file when it is rolled:

```
19 апр 2013 13:00:07,063 INFO  [hdfs-hdfs_sink-roll-timer-0] (org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.renameBucket:379)  - Renaming hdfs://localhost/path/to/data/2013/04/19/12/data.1366358400751.tmp to hdfs://localhost/path/to/data/2013/04/19/12/data.1366358400751
```

[Avro source](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#avro-source) logs each received event batch:

```
19 апр 2013 13:00:07,175 DEBUG [New I/O server worker #1-31] (org.apache.flume.source.AvroSource.appendBatch:222)  - Avro source avro_source: Received avro event batch of 100 events.
```

Also, there are monitoring capabilities in Flume, that allows to report to external system (such as Ganglia) some metrics such as total count of processsed messages, channel size, etc. Take a look at http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#monitoring.